# created CSV file from html page input in python to D3 graph with flask

Tags: python, csv, d3.js, file-io, flask

I have a flask application that I am building. On one page a computation is performed and a csv file is created. This page then links to another page that uses d3 and reads the csv file to display a graph. When I do this, the graph does not display. Is it possible to go from python csv to d3 graph with flask?

This is the pipeline I am trying to create:
Home Page --> User info page (here the user submits some information) -->run a python function that creates a csv file -->the user info page re directs to a page called page2 which takes that csv file as data for the d3 graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv needed to be placed in the static folder. Not the templates folder.